# disqus API missing required parameter: grant_type

Tags: c#, api, url, oauth-2.0, disqus

I am trying to retrieve an access_token through the disqus API.

This is my url:

```
https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/?client_id=cvwNO7HaRwgYDq9anat8j7uzowJ8HBEz8gH7mUnmMhC0BKZZTkObc5d7o242liNG&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=Hrrgy1ZLcLN0qjmZhzXR2owET8cGazcbcGNxTlsWEJYiNfc3JcQLbKx2PYW6yNU7&redirect_uri=http://www.aftenposten.no&code=PM6QYwUJ
```

i'm getting an error: missing required parameter: grant_type

i'm using the following code to get the response:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(getAccessTokenResponse), request);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the form data in the request body and not as url parameters. Give this a try:

```
var uri = "https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/"
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
var data = "client_id=[your client id]"
data += "&grant_type=authorization_code"
data += "&client_secret=[your client secret]"
data += "&redirect_uri=http://www.aftenposten.no&code=PM6QYwUJ"
var postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: You might want to change your api keys, if the ones you've provided are in fact real.